# What is causing Error: Too many re-renders in this code?

Tags: reactjs

Can anybody please look at the following ReactJS component and tell what is causing it to return the error:

`Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Lab() { 

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  const addQuestion = (question) => {
    let q = [...questions];
    q.push(question);
    setQuestions(q);
  }

  addQuestion('What is your name?');
  addQuestion('Where do you belong?');
   
  return (
    <div>
       {
           questions.map( q => <div>{q}</div>)
       }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Lab;
```

**Edit:**
I can use some default values in `useState([])`, but that would make my code much messy because the data structure is quite complicated. That's why I want to push default values from within a helper function. Isn't it possible this way?

Comment: The fact that every time you render the component you add another two questions to the state, triggering another render.

Comment: Simply push the initial values in a mounting `useEffect` (i.e. effect with empty dependency array) so it is run only once when the component mounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PROBLEM

- `Lab` function is executed.
- `addQuestion` is executed which triggers a re-render
- Re-render triggers another execution of `addQuestion`

and thereby causes an infinite loop of re-renders and execution of addQuestion.

#### SOLUTION

- add your default question as the default state in your `Lab` component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const defaultQuestions = [
 'What is your name?', 'What is your name?'
]


function Lab() { 

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(defaultQuestions);

  const addQuestion = (question) => {
    let q = [...questions];
    q.push(question);
    setQuestions(q);
  }
   
  return (
    <div>
       {
           questions.map( q => <div>{q}</div>)
       }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Lab;
```

Comment: Thanks Prateek, please check the Edit in question.

Comment: Where do your values of `defaultQuestions` come from - a server or JSON? If it's JSON, then you have to transform your data in what the state needs, if it's from server, you need to use `React.useEffect` to store the data once it's fetched from API.
Either way, you have to transform your data.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever the state update, the whole function component will re-run again.


Therefore, in your code, when the questions variable is updated, the execution of the addQuestion function will be called again, and the function itself will update the state again, and that causes the infinite loop.


To prevent this kind of situation, it's better to let an event trigger the function.

### Edit

If  adding some default values is your main purpose, this is how you can do it:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Lab() { 
  const isDefaultValueLoaded = useRef(false); 
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  const addQuestion = (question) => {
    let q = [...questions];
    q.push(question);
    setQuestions(q);
  }

  // To set the default values:
  // use an useEffect hook to load the values when the component just mount.
  useEffect(() => {
      // to prevent the infinite loop,
      // use a ref object as a flag to make sure the function will only run once.
      if (isDefaultValueLoaded.current === false) {
        loadDefaultValue();
        isDefaultValueLoaded.current = true;
      }
  }, []);

  // by writing the code above, you can now seperate the logic into an "helper function" as you mentioned.
  const loadDefaultValue = () => {
    addQuestion('What is your name?');
    addQuestion('Where do you belong?');
  }
   
  return (
    <div>
       {
          questions.map(q => <div>{q}</div>)
       }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Lab;
```

Comment: Not much of an answer. It addresses the 'why' of the issue but doesn't provide a "how" for resolution.

Comment: An effect hook with empty (`[]`) dependency array ***will*** run only once when the component mounts, no need for extra reactRef to track first & subsequent renders.